# jQuery .get and refresh on success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
            $.get("lupdate.php", {
                data: forPost, 
                success: function() {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            }
            );
```

Works perfectly in Opera, doesn't work for me in IE, works in Chrome at me but not at my costumer. If i remove the reload tag, it works everywhere.

It's really a matter of time saving, instead of just live time updating with jQuery.

Comment: What version of IE doesn't work? IE9 works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
window.location = './';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try instead of

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

to use

```
windows.location.href ="/yourpage"
```